# How to Create new columns based on other column value and column names and assign value in pandas?

Tags: pandas, group-by, stack, json-normalize

I have a dataframe with 8 columns, lets call it df.

```
Duration Location     a  b  c  d  e  f 
3M       Tuscaloosa   1  2  3  4  5  6
LCM      Tuscaloosa   7  8  7  2  3  5
CW       Tuscaloosa   9  1  0  0  3  1 
PW       Tuscaloosa   1  9  9  9  1  0   
3M       Miami        4  7  0  1  3  8       
LCM      Miami        8  2  7  8  8  1 
CW       Miami        1  3  5  7  9  1  
PW       Miami        8  8  4  4  2  0 
3M       New York     1  4  6  7  8  8 
LCM      New York     3  3  4  4  5  5 
CW       New York     1  1  1  2  2  2  
PW       New York     9  9  9  9  9  9  
3M       San Diego    9  3  5  6  7  1  
LCM      San Diego    1  8  9  0  0  1 
CW       San Diego    7  8  2  1  1  3 
PW       San Diego    0  9  4  6  1  4
```

I would like to create new columns based on the value in 'Duration' and the column name and values of columns a through f. My expected output is

```
Duration Location     a  b  c  d  e  f  3Ma  LCMa   CWa    PWa   3Mb   LCMb   CWb    PWb   3Mc ....
3M       Tuscaloosa   1  2  3  4  5  6  1    null   null   null  2     null   null   null   3
LCM      Tuscaloosa   7  8  7  2  3  5  null 7      null   null  null  8      null   null   null
CW       Tuscaloosa   9  1  0  0  3  1  null null   9      null  null  null   1      null   null
PW       Tuscaloosa   1  9  9  9  1  0  null null   null   1     null  null   null   9      null
3M       Miami        4  7  0  1  3  8  4    null   null   null  7     null   null   null   0
LCM      Miami        8  2  7  8  8  1  null 8      null   null  null  2      null   null   null
CW       Miami        1  3  5  7  9  1  null null   1      null  null  null   3      null   null
PW       Miami        8  8  4  4  2  0  null null   null   8     null  null   null   8      null
3M       New York     1  4  6  7  8  8  1    null   null   null  4     null   null   null   6
LCM      New York     3  3  4  4  5  5  null 3      null   null  null  3      null   null   null
CW       New York     1  1  1  2  2  2  null null   1      null  null  null   1      null   null
PW       New York     9  9  9  9  9  9  null null   null   9     null  null   null   9      null
3M       San Diego    9  3  5  6  7  1  9    null   null   null  3     null   null   null   5
LCM      San Diego    1  8  9  0  0  1  null 1      null   null  null  8      null   null   null
CW       San Diego    7  8  2  1  1  3  null null   7      null  null  null   8      null   null
PW       San Diego    0  9  4  6  1  4  null null   null   0     null  null   null   9      null
```

I have experimented with the .unstack() method but I'm not entirely sure how to tailor it to my situation. I have be unsuccessful with the normalize method as well. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
dfe = df.set_index(['Duration', 'Location', df['Duration']], append=True).unstack()
dfe.columns = [f'{j}{i}' for i, j in dfe.columns]
df.join(dfe.reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output:

```
   Duration    Location  a  b  c  d  e  f  3Ma  CWa  ...  LCMd  PWd  3Me  CWe  LCMe  PWe  3Mf  CWf  LCMf  PWf
0        3M  Tuscaloosa  1  2  3  4  5  6  1.0  NaN  ...   NaN  NaN  5.0  NaN   NaN  NaN  6.0  NaN   NaN  NaN
1       LCM  Tuscaloosa  7  8  7  2  3  5  NaN  NaN  ...   2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN   3.0  NaN  NaN  NaN   5.0  NaN
2        CW  Tuscaloosa  9  1  0  0  3  1  NaN  9.0  ...   NaN  NaN  NaN  3.0   NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0   NaN  NaN
3        PW  Tuscaloosa  1  9  9  9  1  0  NaN  NaN  ...   NaN  9.0  NaN  NaN   NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN   NaN  0.0
4        3M       Miami  4  7  0  1  3  8  4.0  NaN  ...   NaN  NaN  3.0  NaN   NaN  NaN  8.0  NaN   NaN  NaN
5       LCM       Miami  8  2  7  8  8  1  NaN  NaN  ...   8.0  NaN  NaN  NaN   8.0  NaN  NaN  NaN   1.0  NaN
6        CW       Miami  1  3  5  7  9  1  NaN  1.0  ...   NaN  NaN  NaN  9.0   NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0   NaN  NaN
7        PW       Miami  8  8  4  4  2  0  NaN  NaN  ...   NaN  4.0  NaN  NaN   NaN  2.0  NaN  NaN   NaN  0.0
8        3M    New York  1  4  6  7  8  8  1.0  NaN  ...   NaN  NaN  8.0  NaN   NaN  NaN  8.0  NaN   NaN  NaN
9       LCM    New York  3  3  4  4  5  5  NaN  NaN  ...   4.0  NaN  NaN  NaN   5.0  NaN  NaN  NaN   5.0  NaN
10       CW    New York  1  1  1  2  2  2  NaN  1.0  ...   NaN  NaN  NaN  2.0   NaN  NaN  NaN  2.0   NaN  NaN
11       PW    New York  9  9  9  9  9  9  NaN  NaN  ...   NaN  9.0  NaN  NaN   NaN  9.0  NaN  NaN   NaN  9.0
12       3M   San Diego  9  3  5  6  7  1  9.0  NaN  ...   NaN  NaN  7.0  NaN   NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN   NaN  NaN
13      LCM   San Diego  1  8  9  0  0  1  NaN  NaN  ...   0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN   0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN   1.0  NaN
14       CW   San Diego  7  8  2  1  1  3  NaN  7.0  ...   NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0   NaN  NaN  NaN  3.0   NaN  NaN
15       PW   San Diego  0  9  4  6  1  4  NaN  NaN  ...   NaN  6.0  NaN  NaN   NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN   NaN  4.0

[16 rows x 32 columns]
```

Note: Columns are in alphabetical order.

If we want to keep order of columns in the same order as Duration columns, let's convert Duration to Categorical Dtype with order:

```
dur_dtype = pd.CategoricalDtype(df['Duration'].unique(), ordered=True)
df['Duration'] = df['Duration'].astype(dur_dtype)
dfe = df.set_index(['Duration', 'Location', df['Duration']], append=True).unstack()
dfe.columns = [f'{j}{i}' for i, j in dfe.columns]
df.join(dfe.reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output:

```
   Duration    Location  a  b  c  d  e  f  3Ma  LCMa  ...  CWd  PWd  3Me  LCMe  CWe  PWe  3Mf  LCMf  CWf  PWf
0        3M  Tuscaloosa  1  2  3  4  5  6  1.0   NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  5.0   NaN  NaN  NaN  6.0   NaN  NaN  NaN
1       LCM  Tuscaloosa  7  8  7  2  3  5  NaN   7.0  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN   3.0  NaN  NaN  NaN   5.0  NaN  NaN
2        CW  Tuscaloosa  9  1  0  0  3  1  NaN   NaN  ...  0.0  NaN  NaN   NaN  3.0  NaN  NaN   NaN  1.0  NaN
3        PW  Tuscaloosa  1  9  9  9  1  0  NaN   NaN  ...  NaN  9.0  NaN   NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN   NaN  NaN  0.0
4        3M       Miami  4  7  0  1  3  8  4.0   NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  3.0   NaN  NaN  NaN  8.0   NaN  NaN  NaN
5       LCM       Miami  8  2  7  8  8  1  NaN   8.0  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN   8.0  NaN  NaN  NaN   1.0  NaN  NaN
6        CW       Miami  1  3  5  7  9  1  NaN   NaN  ...  7.0  NaN  NaN   NaN  9.0  NaN  NaN   NaN  1.0  NaN
7        PW       Miami  8  8  4  4  2  0  NaN   NaN  ...  NaN  4.0  NaN   NaN  NaN  2.0  NaN   NaN  NaN  0.0
8        3M    New York  1  4  6  7  8  8  1.0   NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  8.0   NaN  NaN  NaN  8.0   NaN  NaN  NaN
9       LCM    New York  3  3  4  4  5  5  NaN   3.0  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN   5.0  NaN  NaN  NaN   5.0  NaN  NaN
10       CW    New York  1  1  1  2  2  2  NaN   NaN  ...  2.0  NaN  NaN   NaN  2.0  NaN  NaN   NaN  2.0  NaN
11       PW    New York  9  9  9  9  9  9  NaN   NaN  ...  NaN  9.0  NaN   NaN  NaN  9.0  NaN   NaN  NaN  9.0
12       3M   San Diego  9  3  5  6  7  1  9.0   NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  7.0   NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0   NaN  NaN  NaN
13      LCM   San Diego  1  8  9  0  0  1  NaN   1.0  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN   0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN   1.0  NaN  NaN
14       CW   San Diego  7  8  2  1  1  3  NaN   NaN  ...  1.0  NaN  NaN   NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN   NaN  3.0  NaN
15       PW   San Diego  0  9  4  6  1  4  NaN   NaN  ...  NaN  6.0  NaN   NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN   NaN  NaN  4.0

[16 rows x 32 columns]
```

There are a couple of pandas tricks in this solution.

1. Using set_index with `df.set_index(df['columnname'])` vs `df.set_index('columnname')`.
   The first, creates a copy of the series and adds that to the index where the second moved the dataframe column series into the index.
2. Use list comprehension to flatten multiIndex column headers.
3. Categorical Dtypes with order creates an order to maintain when unstacking without categorical dtype unstack will sort alphabetically based on column header names.